# If I open url in IE, it works. But if I open same url by api “InternetOpenUrl” then it returns nil. I don't understand what's the reason?

Tags: delphi

If I open mentioned url in IE, it works. But if I open same url by api “InternetOpenUrl” then it returns nil.

url is

```
http://gisservices.datadoors.net/wmsc/__streaminguid.44d023f0-447c-4378-9624-858cd90bb045/wms-c.ashx?SERVICE=WMS&STYLES=&BBOX=-8734904.9955321327,4935096.5230968799,-8659096.1018777788,5002463.5331088305&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&REQUEST=GetMap&TRANSPARENT=false
```

Comment: Does it work with a simple url?

Answer (score 2):

i check your url and is valid (and returns an jpg image), maybe you are not calling the [`InternetOpen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385096%28VS.85%29.aspx) function before to use the [`InternetOpenUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385098%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Check this sample to see how to use the [`InternetOpenUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385098%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

```
var
  hInet     : HINTERNET;
  hFile     : HINTERNET;
begin
  hInet  := InternetOpen(nil, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,nil,nil,0);
  hFile  := InternetOpenURL(hInet,PChar(url),nil,0,0,0);
  try
    if Assigned(hInet) and Assigned(hFile) then
    begin
         //do your stuff here
    end;
  finally
    if Assigned(hFile) then
    InternetCloseHandle(hFile);
    if Assigned(hInet)  then
    InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like a valid url to me. it doesn't start with a protocol and has unescaped special chars like `:` and `>` in it.

Internet explorer probably fixes the url in the frontend, and InternetOpenUrl doesn't.